I want to shut off my 1960s wedgewood futura wall oven
My house was built in 1966. I don't use the oven. What exactly does the shut off valve look like?

I take it this is a gas oven?

Will you be removing it and donating to the Smithsonian ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In this case, I think the bot is wrong...

Typical, though this one has its outlet plugged as well since I'm not using it. 
Note that the valve is open when the handle lines up with the pipe, closed when across the pipe.

Thank you I'm going to try find this
